# Mysql hangs when i add a join statement to my View

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I added a join statement to a mysql query which was originally working without the join statement. After adding 1 inner join statement, the program takes forever to output a result despite having no bugs.

here is the code to the original mysql query:

```
CREATE 
VIEW `tweet_sum` AS
    select 
        `tweets`.`account_id` AS `account_id`,
        `tweets`.`user_screenname` AS `user_screenname`,
        cast(`tweets`.`time` as date) AS `period`,
        max(`tweets`.`followers_count`) AS `followers_count`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) AS `sum_reply`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) AS `sum_retweet`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`) AS `sum_mention`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`) AS `sum_direct`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`) AS `sum_mytweet`,
        (max(`tweets`.`followers_count`) * (((((sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) > 0) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) > 0)) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`) > 0)) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`) > 0)) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`) > 0))) AS `reach`,
        (case
            when (((((sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) + sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`)) > 0) then (((((sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) + sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`)) * max(`tweets`.`followers_count`))
            else `tweets`.`followers_count`
        end) AS `impressions`
    from
        `tweets`
    group by cast(`tweets`.`time` as date) , `tweets`.`user_screenname`;
```

After I add in a join statement below, this code hangs:

```
CREATE 
VIEW `tweet_sum_2` AS
    select 
        `tweets`.`account_id` AS `account_id`,
        `tweets`.`user_screenname` AS `user_screenname`,
        `daily_TWIT_fol`.`followers_count` AS `account_followers_count`,
        cast(`tweets`.`time` as date) AS `period`,
        max(`tweets`.`followers_count`) AS `followers_count`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) AS `sum_reply`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) AS `sum_retweet`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`) AS `sum_mention`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`) AS `sum_direct`,
        sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`) AS `sum_mytweet`,
        (max(`tweets`.`followers_count`) * (((((sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) > 0) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) > 0)) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`) > 0)) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`) > 0)) + (sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`) > 0))) AS `reach`,
        (case
            when (((((sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) + sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`)) > 0) then (((((sum(`tweets`.`is_reply`) + sum(`tweets`.`is_retweet`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mention`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_direct`)) + sum(`tweets`.`is_mytweet`)) * max(`tweets`.`followers_count`))
            else `tweets`.`followers_count`
        end) AS `impressions`
    from
        (`tweets`
        join `daily_TWIT_fol` ON ((`tweets`.`account_id` = `daily_TWIT_fol`.`account_id`)))
    group by cast(`tweets`.`time` as date) , `tweets`.`user_screenname`;
```

So the query has no bugs and i am not sure why. Any ideas?

here are the screen shot of the two tables:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `account_id` indexed in both tables?

Comment: i did `ALTER TABLE socialdash.daily_TWIT_fol ADD INDEX (account_id)` and indexed tweets as well;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your account_id is repetitive in both tables, an inner join would create a huge number of rows. Suppose you have five rows with account_id=1 in the first table, and seven rows with account_id=1 in the second table, the inner join would generate 5x7=35 rows for account_id=1 alone. If the sizes of each table are m and n respectively, the join could potentially generate mn rows.

From the looks of your query, it does seem like you want to join on not just account_id, but on identical dates as well. That should cut down significantly the number of rows generated by join.